# In Table Lay Out How to keep picture box right side and how to reduce space between two row images in window form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

How to get picture box image at right side in `TableLayoutPanel` in c#? At present i am getting two images besides but i don't need. i need only one image to their at extreme right side and i need to remove space between two rows

```
         for (int i = 0, r = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++, r++)
        {
           PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
           pb.ImageLocation = ../imagesDT/answered.gif
           tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
        }
```

Below is my attached image i am getting issue as described above.[image]

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: working but not exactly for what i required . Before image their will be two labels,the second label text goes to another line and all text flow is missing up when i am placing image at right side.@TaW

Comment: Maybe you should 1) tell us the layout of the table (number of columns) and 2) include a new image of what it looks like now. Yopu will have to either add all controls in the right order and without leaving any gaps  or set their right column and possibly row positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Column and the Row those PictureBoxes shall sit in:

```
for (int i = 0, r = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++, r++)
{
    int maxCol = tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount - 1;
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.ImageLocation = ../imagesDT/answered.gif
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(pb, i);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(pb, maxCol );
}
```

You can get the columns' Widths  and the rows' Heights like this:

```
var widths = tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths();
var heights = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights();
```

You can fine-tune the position by setting Margins, e.g.:

```
pb.Margin = New Padding(50, 20, 0, 0);
```

To change the Heights of the Rows you can either use the Designer or you'll can set its Height in the RowStyle of each Row:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[row].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[row].Height = newHeight;
```

To make your table layout visible during your tests you may want to insert code like this in the `CellPaint` event:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random R = new Random(1 + e.Row * 3 + e.Column * 7);
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(
           Color.FromArgb(99, Color.FromArgb( R.Next(123456789)))))
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
}
```